# Android Exception getCause - getMessage

Tags: android, exception

Using the `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` function, I've got the following exception

```
02-22 13:24:34.129: W/System.err(7927): java.io.FileNotFoundException: toto.jpg
```

In the catch clause, a `e.getMessage()` produces

```
toto.jpg
```

But how the get the

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

I tried `e.getCause()` but it returns `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
/* ... */
catch(Exception e) {
    String name = e.getClass().getName();
}
```

Comment: It's not working : The method getName() is undefined for the type Exception

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
exception.toString();
```

see the resource code , and you will understand

Comment: Why toString! did ToString print the whole call stack?

Comment: No, it will print the name of exception , like "java.io.FileNotFoundException" . if you want to see the whole stack message , you should try exception.printStackTrace() or exception.getMessage()